# The last level cache replacement policy

Tags: caching, replace, intel, lru

I've found a blog article about Intel IvyBridge cache replacement policy. He concluded that Ivy Bridge's L3 cache replacement policy is no longer pseudo-LRU.

Under the new cache replacement policy, suppose that there are 4 sets in L3, and set 0 and 1 are using by a process. Set 2 and 3 are available to allocate. If a new process from other cpu tries to load two pages into L3 cache, is it guaranteed that the new process loads its pages into set 2 and 3? In other words, if there are available cache sets in the last level cache, does HW always choose the available sets to load new pages?

Comment: A link to the article would be nice!  Also, unless this behaviour is explicitly documented, any answer here is basically speculation (and maybe experimentation).

Comment: Here's the link to the article(http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement). He observed the behavior of cache of Ivy Bridge and Sandy Bridge processors.